# Android Databinding : ConcurrentModificationException while using ternary operator in method parameter

Tags: java, android, data-binding

I am using databinding in layout file. Following is the relevent code snippet :

```
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_cross"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_close_white"
            app:onClick="@{(v) -> gameManager.dismissAndDestroyDialog()}"
            app:tapEvent="@{(v) -> eventUtils.sendEvent(viewModel.state == State.IN_PROGRESS ? Source.GAME_LOADING : Source.GAME_LOADING_ERROR)}"/>
```

`viewModel`: This is my viewModel for this layout.
`tapEvent` : This I am using for binding Adapter.
`Source` : An enum class 
`State`  : An enum class

When I execute this, I am getting following exception:

```
e: error: cannot generate view binders java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
e: 

e:      at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1437)
e:      at java.util.HashMap$ValueIterator.next(HashMap.java:1466)
e:      at android.databinding.tool.expr.CallbackExprModel.seal(CallbackExprModel.java:63)
e:      at android.databinding.tool.expr.LambdaExpr.setup(LambdaExpr.java:154)
e:      at android.databinding.tool.Binding.resolveCallbackParams(Binding.java:93)
e:      at android.databinding.tool.BindingTarget.resolveCallbackParams(BindingTarget.java:175)
e:      at android.databinding.tool.LayoutBinder.<init>(LayoutBinder.java:237)
e:      at android.databinding.tool.DataBinder.<init>(DataBinder.java:52)
e:      at android.databinding.tool.CompilerChef.ensureDataBinder(CompilerChef.java:88)
e:      at android.databinding.tool.CompilerChef.sealModels(CompilerChef.java:187)
e:      at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessExpressions.writeResourceBundle(ProcessExpressions.java:184)
```

Please comment if you need more details. I have tried this in different xml file with String param also. Nothing is working for me. Is it a known bug? If so, is there any work around for this?

Note : eventUtils class is written in Kotlin But I don't see that as an issue here.

Edit : viewModel.state is an Observable field of State enum data type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `viewModel.state` is an `Observable` field use this:

```
app:tapEvent="@{(v) -> eventUtils.sendEvent(viewModel.state.get() == State.IN_PROGRESS ? Source.GAME_LOADING : Source.GAME_LOADING_ERROR)}"
```

The `get()` method is compulsory to use inside lambda.